# Django3 + Apache2. When I use the administrator to upload image in the background, I got Server Error (500)

Tags: django, apache, http, django-models, internal-server-error

I'm beginner in Django.

In Django3 + Apache2, when I use the administrator to upload image in the background, I got Server Error (500). I go to check the accesslog, it show ""POST /admin/mainapp/product/add/ HTTP/1.1" 500 417".
But when I use command "python3 manage.py runserver" to runserver, it work well.
I don't know how to solve this probelm, Please help!

Following is my code:

setting.py

```
from pathlib import Path

import os

SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-ppa-x(eyccb857-@uq$5qx$srwf#%$j4i-j7s=&m8mf0l@0#9_'

DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mainapp',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'web_2T4GAME.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'web_2T4GAME.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
]
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/staticfiles' this

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = '/var/www/media'
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.deletion import CASCADE
from django.db.models.fields import CharField

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    image = models.ImageField(null = True, upload_to = 'product')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=CASCADE,null=True)
    Inventory = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

wsgi.py

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/var/www/myproject')
sys.path.append('/var/www/myproject/myproject')

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'web_2T4GAME.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

000-default.conf

```
Alias /static/ /var/www/staticfiles/
Alias /media/ /var/www/media/

<Directory /var/www/staticfiles>
                Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/media>
                Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/myproject/myproject/>
       <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
       </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-home=/var/www/VENV python-path=/var/www/myproject/myproject
WSGIProcessGroup myproject
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
```

Comment: Can you add the related apache error logs?

Comment: Errorlog
`[Thu Dec 16 00:00:30.849998 2021] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 53593:tid 140459089951808] AH00489: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.6.8 Python/3.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Dec 16 00:00:30.850036 2021] [core:notice] [pid 53593:tid 140459089951808] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'`

Comment: Sorry. If the error log shows nothing, I don't know where it is. Try setting `DEBUG = True` and restarting the server to test if it shows a django's debug page to know more about the error.

Comment: I did as you said and I got this:
`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/media/product/apple.jpg'`

Comment: Thanks for help me to find error! I change the media folder permissions and I fixed  it.